# how to create a generic background image binding from a control template?

Tags: wpf

i have button with this style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="btnStyle">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Image x:Name="img" Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}"
                                 Stretch="None"></Image>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource imgClose_P}"/>
                                 </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{DynamicResource imgClose_H}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
```

As you can see i'm binding the ImageSource to the Tag property of the button.
And in the Tag property i'm binding it to a ResourceDictionary that store this bitmap:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="imgClose_N" UriSource="..\AppImages\mainWindow\TopBanner\CloseButton_sN.png" />
```

this gives me the ability to use this "Imagebutton" all over the application with different background images and one template.
the problem is how to keep this generic approach with triggers?
i would like the IsMouseOver trigger to change the background image but to bind it to some property of the control and not to write it hard coded in the control template.
how can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already suggest by calling it an "Imagebutton", you may derive from `Button` and define some image properties to bind to, e.g. `BackgroundImage`, `MouseOverImage`, etc.

An alternative to deriving from `Button` would be to use [attached properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx) to set the images and bind to those in your style, but these attached properties would also have to be defined somewhere, which doesn't make it simpler.

Here's an example for the first solution:

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalBackgroundImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "NormalBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MouseOverBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PressedBackgroundImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "PressedBackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImageButton));

    public ImageSource NormalBackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalBackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource MouseOverBackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MouseOverBackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }

    public ImageSource PressedBackgroundImage
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PressedBackgroundImageProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

and an appropriate style below. Note that this style also has a [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) for the button's content, and that it uses regular bindings with `RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}` instead of TemplateBindings. These are evaluated at runtime.

```
<Style TargetType="local:ImageButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ImageButton">
                <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}">
                    <Image x:Name="img" Source="{Binding NormalBackgroundImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Stretch="None"/>
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding MouseOverBackgroundImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="img" Property="Source" Value="{Binding PressedBackgroundImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You would have to define or replace the XAML namespace `local` with a mapping to the namespace/assembly that contains the class `ImageButton`.

The button could then be use like this:

```
<local:ImageButton
    Margin="10"
    NormalBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Desert.jpg"
    PressedBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Tulips.jpg"
    MouseOverBackgroundImage="C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg"
    Content="Click Me"/>
```

Comment: can u please post an example of the first suggestion ?

Comment: to be clearer - i would like my controls to have 3 properties :normal bg image , hover bg image and pressed bg image so in the template i'll bind it to them.

Comment: Of course, but later. I'll have to go to a meeting right now :-) Two hours or so. See you later.

Comment: thanks alot - i'll try to dig your suggestion from web in the mean while